# How to make a cursor contrast with the background?

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

For the browsers I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, and IE), the built in crosshair cursor changes to white when it is over a black image and black when it is over a white image.  Is there a way to make custom cursors that do this?

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.crosshair {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<div class="black crosshair"></div>
<div class="white crosshair"></div>
```

[Original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/jwunm/).

Thanks much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CUR file format is explained in reasonable detail [here](http://oreilly.com/www/centers/gff/formats/miccur/index.htm). In particular, it mentions the following:

> A monochrome (1-bit) icon or cursor will contain only four possible pixels values: black, white, transparent, and inverted. A transparent or inverted pixel may be either black or white in color. The color palette will contain only two colors, which are black (entry zero) and white (entry one). The transparent color is the original color of the display pixels. Inverted is the inverse color of the display pixels.

Comment: Update:  I've tried creating this with RealWorld Cursor (you set inverted transparency to 00FFFFFF for any inverted pieces you want to draw), and the cursor works as expected in IE.  However, the cursor shows up as a black box in Chrome and as completely transparent in Firefox.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox don't really support .CUR or .ANI files well, or at all. Sorry.

Comment: The link goes to a 404 page.
Putting in a new one that explain the same concept.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/drawing-monochrome-pointers